# Prolog arg built in personal implementation, don't work

Tags: prolog

I have some trouble with an exercise that ask me to implement the classic **arg** predicate in Prolog.

```
arg(?Arg, +Term, ?Value)
```

Where Arg it is the index of the argument in the arguments list of a Term. Value it is the value of this argument.

For example:

```
arg(1, t(f(X),Y,a), Value)
Value = f(X).
```

Because f(x) it is the first argument in the arguments list of the t main functor.

So I am tryng to resolve the exercise using the univ =.. predicates in this way:

```
argom(ArgIndex,Term,ValueArg):- Term =.. [_|ArgsList],
                            element_n(ArgIndex,ArgsList,ValueArg).

element_n(1,[ValueArg,_],ValueArg).

element_n(N,[_,Tail],ValueArg):- N1 is N-1,
                                 element_n(N1,Tail,ValueArg).
```

Where **argom** relation it is my personal implementation of the **arg** built in predicate...

The problem is that solution don't work...the idea is that I have an **argom** predicate that take:

1. **ArgIndex**: the index of the argument that I would obtain.
2. **Term** that is an expression like: **f(a,b,c)**
3. **ValueArg**: that rappresent the value of the argument having **ArgIndex** as index

So, if I have **f(a,b,c)** as **Term** and **ArgIndex** is 1, then **ArgValue** have to be **a**.

I use the **unive** built in predicate that, starting from my **Term** create a list where in the head there is the main functor of my **Term** and in the tail (named **ArgsList**) there is the arguments list of the main functor.

I would the nth argument so I would the  nth element in the ArgsList and to obtain it I define the **element_n** relation that take: ArgIndex, ArgsList, ValueArg.

If I would the **first** element in the list the **ArgIndex** value is 1 and the base case it is matched:

```
 element_n(1,[ValueArg,_],ValueArg).
```

So the ValueArg is in the head of my ArgsList argument list and unify it.

Otherwise call the rule to obtain the nth element in the ArgsList

The problem is that when I consult it don't work and the answer is always: **fail** also if I try to obtain the first element (that is the simplest case in wich I use the base case rule)

Looking at the trace I have the same situation:

```
[trace] 9 ?- argom(1,f(a,b,c),a).
   Call: (6) argom(1, f(a, b, c), a) ? creep
   Call: (7) f(a, b, c)=..[_G3148|_G3149] ? creep
   Exit: (7) f(a, b, c)=..[f, a, b, c] ? creep
   Call: (7) element_n(1, [a, b, c], a) ? creep
   Fail: (7) element_n(1, [a, b, c], a) ? creep
   Fail: (6) argom(1, f(a, b, c), a) ? creep
false.
```

So, it call the argom rule saying to it: **"Is it TRUE that the first argument of the main functor is a?"**

It use in the right way the **univ =..** built in predicate generating the list **[f, a, b, c]** from my Term **f(a, b, c)**

Now it call the **element_n** predicate and this is the base case so have to unify the **ValueArg** with the **head of the list** but then it **fail**

I have also try to ask: **What is the value of ValueArg if ArgIndex value is 1 and the Term is f(a,b,c)?**

```
[trace] 10 ?- argom(1,f(a,b,c),ValueArg).
   Call: (6) argom(1, f(a, b, c), _G3483) ? creep
   Call: (7) f(a, b, c)=..[_G3553|_G3554] ? creep
   Exit: (7) f(a, b, c)=..[f, a, b, c] ? creep
   Call: (7) element_n(1, [a, b, c], _G3483) ? creep
   Fail: (7) element_n(1, [a, b, c], _G3483) ? creep
   Fail: (6) argom(1, f(a, b, c), _G3483) ? creep
false.
```

So it appear clear that the problem is that seems to have some problem to unify the head of the list with the ValueArg in this rule:

```
element_n(1,[ValueArg,_],ValueArg).
```

Why?

Comment: Your trace exactly shows the point of failure, twice: steps 4 and 5. Why do you write this huge question?

Comment: You're right, this was a stupid error !!! I am a beginner with Prolog and sometimes I am feel lost...writing huge question I try to be clear and I try to do the point of situation also in my mind...maybe this is another stupid question but...what you exactly mean when you say: "the point of failure, twice: steps 4 and 5"? do you mean that appear clear that the problem was when try to enter in: element_n(1,[ValueArg,_],ValueArg) rule?

Comment: Yes. On line 4 is the predicate call that failed (in both traces you show). This should already tell you that you should start looking for the source of your problem there. If you had tried out the `element_n` predicate, you would have noticed that it does not behave the way you expect. You could then A) double check your implementation against the example I gave you in your previous question, or B) ask why your `element_n` fails, in far less words. The whole "Prolog arg built in personal implementation, don't work" question has actually very little to do with your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivial: it's `[Head|Tail]`, not `[Head,Tail]`. This: `[A,B]` matches a two-element list!

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990890/how-to-implement-arg-predicate-in-prolog/15992019#15992019)....